# ApolloClient: Is it possible to trigger side-effect if `onError` retry attempt fails

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using ApolloClient in a React application. According to the ApolloClient docs on [Error Handling](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling):

> If your retried operation also results in errors, those errors are not passed to your onError link to prevent an infinite loop of operations. This means that an onError link can retry a particular operation only once.

The problem I face is that I cannot easily know if the retry attempt failed. I need to know this so that I can trigger a side-effect, namely in my case if re-authentication fails, redirect to an unauthorized page. Is there any way to trigger a redirect after a retry attempt in `onError` occurs and fails?

Note that this is different from `RetryLink`, as that is for handling Network Errors while the above that I describe is for handling GraphqlErrors.